# How to access camera in background using ionic capacitor/cordova on Android 9

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, openvidu

I'm trying to get access to the camera while the app is in the background (e.g. the phone is locked). As it turns out, Android 9 does not allow to do that unless you are trying to get access using a foreground service. I'm using ionic framework in my application (camera is being accessed using `navigator` interface). Is there any way to run JS from the foreground service using native plugins or by any other means?

Comment: The only js allowed to run in the background is via a registered service worker. But since service worker as a ~web worker has no access to "window" etc, most likely you can't establish native plugin to js bridge there. But interesting problem;)